# Display JPG based upon URL

Tags: html

I have a JPG in the header section of a responsive HTML page. I want to use the same site content for multiple domains that will point to my single set of files at my hosted URL. Example : mysite.com will host all files. But a second site - example theirsite.com will point in a forward to my hosted files location.

All the content will be the same, EXCEPT FOR the one image file (logo.png) or can be any name, but I would like to see if I can image-substitute 1 file (logo.png) to render so that, when visitors come to mysite.com, they see my file. When visitors come to theirsite.com they will see the logo file for theirsite.com instead of for mysite.com Sorry if I have not explained this professionally.

Comment: Step 1: Pick a programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two real ways to do this.  The best way is to handle it server-side.

You would need some sort of dynamic site generation, such as PHP.  As the site isn't changing on each request, I'd recommend doing this generation ahead of time.  Then you can utilize static hosting on CDNs and such.  The specifics of how you do this depend on your technology choice.  And, it matters little what you pick.

Doing the switch server-side is better, as crawlers will be able to see the right version of the site.  Most crawlers don't run client-side code.

The second option is to handle it client-side.  In this case, I'd recommend including a site definition file for each domain and writing some JavaScript to check the hostname the site was loaded on, and load the right site definition file.  That file could contain elements and attributes to replace.  Again, this is less desirable of an option, but still possible.